# PHP and MySQL query set to session

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Every time I run it, it automatically assigns to verified. Any ideas?

```html
$verify = "SELECT verification_status 
    FROM users 
    WHERE username = '$username' ";
$result2 = $conn->query($verify);

if ($result2 == 'verified') {
    $_SESSION['verifiedstatus'] = 'verified';
} elseif ($result2 == 'pending') {
    $_SESSION['verifiedstatus'] = 'pending';
} elseif ($result2 == 'unverified') {
    $_SESSION['verifiedstatus'] = 'unverified';
}
```

Comment: there are many syntax errors here. Not quoting values and assigning rather than comparing. It's also unknown if the session was started.

Comment: $result2 = 'verified' -> $result2 == 'verified'

Comment: you're also missing some code to iterate over the query. You can't just "check if it's equal to something" like that.

Comment: Session was started, values quoted now. @Fred-ii- What do you mean code to iterate over the query

Comment: $result2 is an object not a string

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please post your responses a an answer, they helped me get it fixed. It is working properly now after making some adjustments to iterate the query. Thank you.

Comment: @BlakeConnally Done. Sorry, I was away for a bit since I was getting supper ready. Cheers

Comment: Instead of a pile of `if` statements, why not either a `switch` or an [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) test?

Comment: @tadman I apologize, I am still learning to be more effective. I will research switch and in_array thank you.

Comment: @BlakeConnally Nothing wrong with learning. Just giving you a few things to look into so you can broaden your tool set.

Comment: @tadman Wow! That's amazing, just rearranged it using switch. So much more effective. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *@Fred-ii- Please post your responses a an answer, they helped me get it fixed. It is working properly now after making some adjustments to iterate the query. Thank you. – Blake Connally*

As OP's request.

You haven't iterated over the query.

A loop is required to do this, such as a `while` loop and checking if a row equals something.

You also seem to be learning (MySQL), therefore I suggest that you read up on SQL injection:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Since you may be querying from possible user input.

Comment: Correct, thank you. I did a while loop and it worked perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @BlakeConnally I made a slight edit to my answer about SQL injection. You may want to read up on that, *cheers* (You will need to reload it in order to see the addition).